# Finding the system username of the user running a python program?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a python web scraper using selenium that also includes loading the uBlock Origin extension. How do I make the program detect the user's system username, so I can put it in the default extension path, or, if there is a way to do it, load the extension without it?

I tried using %USERNAME% and it does not work.

Comment: Use os module. Call `os.environ.get('USER')` for user name and `os.environ.get('HOME')` for home directory.

Comment: @Firelord It doesn't work, Python reports the username as "None" - this results in the extension not loading.

Comment: Add in the question the output of `print(os.environ)`.

Comment: @Firelord I ran the command and in the output I found that there are HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH keys that contain the values I needed. However, there is no USER key.
Anyway, through that I got the results I wanted.

Comment: os module provide OS specific information. USER and HOME are Unix and Linux specific. You are using Windows as it seems, that's why you could not use those keys.

Answer (score 0):

For username:

```
import os
print(os.getlogin())
```